# libmono-winforms2.0-cil missing (deleted) from xenial release

Tags: apt, 16.04, software-recommendation

The package `libmono-winforms2.0-cil` isn't available in the repositories for 16.04. Is there a replacement for it?

I see that it was deleted about 4 months ago (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/libmono-winforms2.0-cil)

I require this for a 3rd party app from Pololu to drive one of it's servo controllers.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically, you might use a "third party" repository to have your packages back.

Type in this:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF`

then

`echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list`

then

`sudo apt-get update`

After that, you should be able to install libmono-winforms2.0-cil with:

`sudo apt-get install libmono-winforms2.0-cil`

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me out with this :). It certainly helped. Altough there were still dependency issues trying to install the Winforms package, I opted to go to v4. I'll get the source for the app and try recompile. In any event, it worked out